# Migrations.cs is not created successfully

Tags: c#, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am creating new module called "sms" in orchard cms using webmatrix. I create it successfully but when i generate "migrateions.cs", it doesn't generated successfully.

my `sms.cs` class in Model is given below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;

namespace SMSs.Model{
public class smsrecord:ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual int ID{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual char is_deleted{get;set;}
}
public class smspart:ContentPart<smsrecord>
{

    [Required]
    public int ID
    {
        get{return ID=Record.ID;}
        set{Record.ID=value;} 
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get{return Name=Record.Name;}
        set{Record.Name=value;}
    }
    public char is_deleted
    {
        get{return is_deleted=Record.is_deleted;}
        set{Record.is_deleted=value;}
    }
}
```

and the generated `Migrations.cs` class is as follow

```
using System;


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData.Builders;
using Orchard.Core.Contents.Extensions;
using Orchard.Data.Migration;

namespace sms {
    public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

        public int Create() {


            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

the "migrations.cs" is not generated successfully why?? Please help

Comment: How do you know the migration is not generated successfully?

Comment: In fact, your migration looks fine to me. Why do think it is not correct?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin because no table is created..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class itself is generated properly, although it lacks code for creating appropriate tables because you didn't adhere to naming conventions for your record class.

Data migration code generation requires you to follow several conventions in order for it to work properly. I.e.:

- Namespace of a record must end with `.Models` or `.Records`
- There has to exist a public property named `Id`
- All properties have to be virtual (required by NHibernate anyway)
- Class cannot be sealed
- Class cannot be abstract
- Class has to implement `IContent` or be a subclass of `ContentPartRecord`

In your case, the namespace (should end with `.Models`) and incorrect casing of `ID` (should be `Id`) are the culprits.

Comment: Also, `is_deleted` should be named `IsDeleted` and should be a bool, not a char. And while we're at it, it would be better to use Store and Retrieve than access the record properties directly.

Comment: I second that - since Orchard 1.8 we don't have to use backing records unless there's a good reason for it. Store/Retrieve is usually the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Migration.cs still not created completely. but i figure it out and do it manually and table is created when I enable the module.

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd: that's not exactly how I meant it. Store and Retrieve can also be used with record-based parts, which still have their place if those properties are likely to be queried against. `IsDeleted` sounds like something you'd like to filter against.